# When is the last term of a polynomial larger than the sum of all previous terms?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, polynomials, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I recall seeing a simple derivation of the $M>1$ for which $|a_0+a_1x+...+a_{2n}x^{2n}|<|a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}|$ when $x>M$, but I cannot remember it.

Comment: Please state the hypotheses completely. We can guess at what you mean, but should we have to?

Comment: Is stating that $x $ is real and $n $ is a natural number sufficient?

Comment: Coefficients are real.

Comment: so you are asking when the constant term is greater than all the rest ?

Comment: I want to know when the highest-power term is larger than the sum of all the other terms.

Comment: here's a start when is it larger than the next highest power term ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $|\sum_{i=0}^{2n} {a_ix^i}| \le \sum_{i=0}^{2n} {|a_ix^i|} \le a\sum_{i=0}^{2n} {|x|^i} = a \frac{|x|^{2n+1}-1}{|x|-1} $ where $a = \max_{0 \le i \le 2n} \{|a_i|\} > 0 $

Then 
$$ x > a' + 1 \implies x - 1 > a' \implies x^{2n+1}(x - 1) > x^{2n+1}a' \implies x^{2n+1}(x-1) > x^{2n+1}a' - a' \implies x^{2n+1} > a' \frac{x^{2n+1} - 1}{x - 1} \implies |a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}| > a \frac{x^{2n+1} - 1}{x - 1} = a \frac{|x|^{2n+1}-1}{|x|-1} $$ where $a' = \frac{a}{|a_{2n+1}|} > 0 $